# Can we use Third Party Payment SDK other-then Apple Pay

Tags: stripe-payments, in-app-purchase, strip, paypal-rest-sdk, applepay

My app is dependent on Camera. We are showing alerts and live view of camera in app. User can purchase plans to enable AI feature on camera firmware and we are also providing cloud storage for history. So can we use other payment sdk other then Apple pay as our app is dependent on Camera(Hardware). We are not restricting any feature inside the app. All features are turn on on Camera firmware.

We want to use Third party payment gateway not Apple pay as our app is dependent on hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the description, your use case sounds like in-app purchase, which is different from Apple Pay. You can read this [doc](https://support.stripe.com/questions/apple-pay-or-in-app-purchases-for-mobile-application-payments) to learn the difference between Apple Pay and in-app purchase.

For in-app purchases, you have to use Apple's [in-app purchase SDK](https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/).